# Div manipulation | Python | Urllib

Tags: python, urllib2

I am using urllib to do web scraping in python. On the webpage I want to scrape, I have the following HTML Code :

```
  <module type="Product Model">
    <div class = ""> 
      <div class="">
         <div class = "a on"> ......  </div>
         <div class = "b"> </div>
         <div class = "b"> </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </module>
```

If we manipulate the div by adding "on", we can access all the data inside the div.

```
 <div class = "b on"> .... </div>
 <div class = "c on"> .... </div>
```

I want to access all the data inside my module  tag, but while I am scraping the data from the web page, I can see only the values of those div which has "on" appended on their class i.e on

```
  div class = "a on"
```

**How do I access all the divs ? Is there any way to manipulate the div from python ?**

Here is the python code :

```
 print (soup.find("module", {"id":"Product Model"}))
```

Comment: [edit] your Question with the Output of  ` print (soup.find(...`

Comment: I came to know that I need a JavaScript interpreter in order to do this. What happens is that, the data below some div's can only be seen when the JS runs on that div, which is done on client side.